# Can't able to access email field using facebook sdk for IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API, but I can't figure out how to get a logged-in users email address.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] allowLoginUI:NO
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    // Handler for session state changes
    // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
    // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
}];
```

Comment: change your allowLoginUI to YES.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955635/ios-facebook-sdk-3-1-add-permission-when-login

Comment: There must be some problem with your permissions

Comment: email permission is available for my developer account, but even though I am not able to get the email id from Facebook.